# Inequality for invertible matrices with natural number entries 2.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix with entries in the natural numbers (including 0).

> Question: In case A has on the diagonal entries all equal to one and determinant $\pm 1$, is the sum of all entries of A always larger than or equal to the sum of entries of the inverse of A?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. If A only has diagonal entries equal to 1, isn't that the identity matrix?

Comment: @Time4Tea I mean that on the diagonal there are only entries 1, the other entries can be different outside the diagonal!

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&5&1\\0&1&5\\0&0&1},\quad
A^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&-5&24\\0&1&-5\\0&0&1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, do you know also an example with A having only entries 0-1 with those assumptions?